# Accessing a WCF service from ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, wcf, binding

I'm trying to access a WCF service, exposed using basicHttpBinding, inside an ASP.NET 2.0 web application.  The services uses Entity Framework 4.0, and its business entities were created using the ADO.NET Self-Tracking Entity Generator T4 template.  I can attach to the service from the ASP.NET 2.0 app just fine and compile, but at run time, when I try to call the service to save, I get the following error:

The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:foc. The InnerException message was 'The use of type 'Business.App.ObjectChangeTracker' as a get-only collection is not supported with NetDataContractSerializer.  Consider marking the type with the CollectionDataContractAttribute attribute or the SerializableAttribute attribute or adding a setter to the property.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

I don't have anything fancy on the service declaration; just the normal ServiceContract and OperationContract attributes.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILSRPipelineServiceEndPoint
{
    [OperationContract]
    LSRRequestTypeMapping[] GetRequestTypeMappings();

    [OperationContract]
    LSRResponseTypeMapping[] GetResponseTypeMappings();

    [OperationContract]
    ServiceResult<FOCResponse> ValidateFOC(FOCResponse foc);

    [OperationContract]
    ServiceResult<FOCResponse> SendFOC(FOCResponse foc);

    [OperationContract]
    ref_SourceType GetGatewaySourceType();
}
```

All of the objects shown are marked with [DataContract(IsReference = true)]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or what I can do to resolve this?  Thanks a ton, all!

Comment: Is the error client side or server side?

Comment: It's server side.  The SendFOC method worked fine until I added the return type (it was previously void), so that's definitely the root of the problem.  I'm just not sure how to solve it.

Comment: I changed the return type on the ValidateFOC and SendFOC methods to not include any objects in the return object graph, as well as nothing that uses a generic.  The new return type is just a single bool field, and a single string array field.  I still get this error.  D'oh!  Frustrating!

Comment: Are your objects entity framework objects?

Comment: The NetDataContractSerializer won't work with a .NET 2.0 client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately changed to using View Model POCO's, rather than trying to send across the raw objects with their state tracking components.  Thanks, all!  Lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're using the NetDataContractSerializer rather than the DataContractSerializer.  From what I've read only the DataContractSerializer is supported for self-tracking entities.

See this page:[MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/0ce0ac28-6137-4e34-9e38-bfa4769724c4)